# Knockoutjs - Nested group array with self referencing many to many checkbox list

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a nested array of group product options in a grid. I would like to have a popup editor which list all the products (productoptionrows) of each grouped product option and allow a user to check the relations between them. I have come across example of many to many relationships but not seen a example of a self referencing grouped many to many.

Consider the following array data structure:

```
[{
grouptitle: "User Band",
productoptionrows: [{
    id: "1",
    producttitle: "25-100",
    relatedproductoptionrows: [{
        id: "4",
        title: '1 Year'
    }, {
        id: "5",
        title: '2 Year'
    }, {
        id: "6",
        title: '3 Year'
    }]
}]
```

A user will be able to define groups with a title and add a list of products to that group. Once the user has added all the groups and related products, then the user could could click on a popup button("Lookup") the check the relations between the products of each group.

The problem I'm having is in the popup, when you click "Lookup" for each product option to set its relations and also default the popup so that it relations are already checked. I think the root to my problem is im trying to combine multiple nested arrays but im not sure how to structure the view model/data to cope with this logic.

I have set up a fiddler below that show my issue below:

```js
/*Select Options*/
var initialData = [{
    grouptitle: "User Band",
    productoptionrows: [{
        id: "1",
        producttitle: "25-100",
        relatedproductoptionrows: [{
            id: "4",
            producttitle: '1 Year'
        }, {
            id: "5",
            producttitle: '2 Year'
        }, {
            id: "6",
            producttitle: '3 Year'
        }]
    }, {
        id: "2",
        producttitle: "101-250",
        relatedproductoptionrows: [{
            id: "7",
            producttitle: '1 Year'
        }, {
            id: "8",
            producttitle: '2 Year'
        }, {
            id: "9",
            producttitle: '3 Year'
        }]
    }, {
        id: "3",
        producttitle: "251-500",
        relatedproductoptionrows: [{
            id: "10",
            producttitle: '1 Year'
        }, {
            id: "11",
            producttitle: '2 Year'
        }, {
            id: "12",
            producttitle: '3 Year'
        }]
    }]
}, {
    grouptitle: "Please select the number of years license",
    productoptionrows: [{
        id: "4",
        producttitle: "1 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "5",
        producttitle: "2 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "6",
        producttitle: "3 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "7",
        producttitle: "1 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "8",
        producttitle: "2 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "9",
        producttitle: "3 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "10",
        producttitle: "1 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "11",
        producttitle: "2 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "12",
        producttitle: "3 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }]
}];


$(document).ready(function () {
    /*Models*/
    var mappingOptions = {
        'productoptionrows': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new productoptionrow(options.data);
            }
        }
    };
    var mappingOptionsPR = {
        create: function (options) {
            return new productoptionrow(options.data);
        }
    };
    var productoptionrow = function (por) {
        var self = ko.mapping.fromJS(por, {}, this);
        self.relatedproductoptionrowscsv = ko.computed(function () {
            return $(por.relatedproductoptionrows).map(function () {
                return this.id;
            }).get().join(',');
        }, self);
        self.selectedrelatedproductoptionrows = ko.observableArray($(por.relatedproductoptionrows).map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get());
    };
    var ProductOptionModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.productoptions = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
        self.isOpen = ko.observable(false);
        self.selectedrelatedproductoptionrows = ko.observableArray([]);
        /*Control Events*/
        self.addProductOption = function () {
            var newoption = ko.mapping.fromJS({
                grouptitle: "Please select the number of years license",
                productoptionrows: ko.observableArray([{
                    id: "15",
                    producttitle: "25-100",
                    relatedproductoptionrows: []
                }, {
                    id: "16",
                    producttitle: "101-250",
                    relatedproductoptionrows: []
                }, {
                    id: "17",
                    producttitle: "251-500",
                    relatedproductoptionrows: []
                }])
            }, mappingOptions);
            self.productoptions.push(newoption);
        };
        self.copyProductOption = function (productoption) {
            var copy = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(productoption), mappingOptions);
            self.productoptions.push(copy);
        };
        self.removeProductOption = function (productoption) {
            self.productoptions.remove(productoption);
        };
        self.addProductOptionRow = function (productoption) {
            var newrow = ko.mapping.fromJS({
                id: "15",
                producttitle: "25-100",
                relatedproductoptionrows: []
            }, mappingOptionsPR);
            productoption.productoptionrows.push(newrow);
        };
        self.removeProductOptionRow = function (productoption) {
            $.each(self.productoptions(), function () {
                this.productoptionrows.remove(productoption)
            })
        };
        self.open = function (productoption, event) {
            self.selectedrelatedproductoptionrows(productoption.relatedproductoptionrows);
            self.isOpen(true);
        };
        self.close = function () {
            self.isOpen(false);
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ProductOptionModel(initialData), document.getElementById('page-wrapper'));

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/gvas/knockout-jqueryui/075b303a/dist/knockout-jqueryui.min.js"></script>

<div id="page-wrapper">
        <div>
            <button title="Add Group Option" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.addProductOption'>Add Group Option</button>
        </div>
        <div id="options" data-bind="foreach: productoptions">
            <div style="padding:10px;margin:20px;background-color:whitesmoke">
                <table class="option-header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Group Title <span class="required">*</span></th>
                            <th>
                                <button title="Copy" type="button" class="" style="" data-bind='click: $root.copyProductOption'>Copy Group</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <button title="Delete Option" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.removeProductOption'>Delete Group Option</button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr style="height:36px;">
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" data-bind='value: grouptitle'>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div>
                    <table class="option-header-rows" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="headings">
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th colspan="2" class="type-title">Product Title <span class="required">*</span></th>
                                <th>Related Ids</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: productoptionrows">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <input required type="text" style="width:40px" data-bind='value: id'>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <input type="text" value="25-100" data-bind='value: producttitle'>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" data-bind='value: relatedproductoptionrowscsv' name="isdefault"><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.open, disable: $root.isOpen">Lookup</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button title="Delete Row" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.removeProductOptionRow'>Delete Row</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">
                                    <button title="Add New Row" type="button" data-bind='click: $root.addProductOptionRow'>Add New Row</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- popup -->
        <div data-bind="dialog: { isOpen: isOpen,title:'Select relations', modal:true }">
            <div data-bind="foreach: $root.productoptions">
                <div data-bind='text: grouptitle'></div>
                <div data-bind="foreach: productoptionrows">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value:id, checkedValue: selectedrelatedproductoptionrows" style="width:auto" />
                        ID <span data-bind='text: id'></span> - <span data-bind='text: producttitle'></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
    </div>
```

I'm really hoping somebody can understand what im trying to achieve and get this working as i have been stcuk on this for a few days now. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I removed the "UI" part of your code, since that's what stopped me from taking the time to answer the previous time you posted this question...

The problem you're describing can be quite complicated. The key is to use `ko.computed` properties that have a `read` and a `write` option.

So you have two lists: `Products` and `Options`. Each product can have one or more options. Each option therefore can have 0 or more linked products. (This is what you mean by the many-to-many relation, right?)

We start out by rendering a list of procuts. Each product shows its options with a checkbox. It stores a list of checked options.

```
function Product(data) {
  this.title = data.producttitle;
  this.id = data.id;

  this.options = data.relatedproductoptionrows;
  this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
};
```

With the HTML:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: options">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedOptions, checkedValue: $data">

    <span data-bind="text: producttitle"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Whenever you (un)check one of the options, the option object is added or removed from the `selectedOptions` array.

Now starts the hardest part: when we want to render the `Option` instead of the `Product`, we need to (A) *compute* which products are related, and we need to (B) make sure these products `selectedOptions` arrays stay up to date when we choose to alter the relationship.

Starting with (A): we can define the products related to an option like so:

```
// Every product that has an option with my `id` is a related product
relatedProducts = products.filter(
  p => p.options.some(o => o.id === this.id)
);
```

Each of these relations has a computed `checked` state that can be read from or written to. That's where the read/write `ko.computed` comes in. For each relation (`linkedObj`), the `checked` state is defined: (B)

```
checked: ko.computed({
  // When the current `option` is in the linked product's
  // selected options, it must be checked
  read: () => p.selectedOptions().includes(linkedObj),

  // When forcing the checked to true/false,
  // we need to either add or remove the option to the
  // linked product's selection
  write: val => val 
    ? p.selectedOptions.push(linkedObj)
    : p.selectedOptions.remove(linkedObj)
})
```

I can imagine the concept's quite hard to grasp... and my explanation might be lacking. The example below shows this concept in action. Note that it's not optimized for speed (lots of looping through arrays) and only the checked properties are made observable.

```js
const products = getProducts();
const options = getOptions();
  
function Product(data) {
  this.title = data.producttitle;
  this.id = data.id;
  
  this.options = data.relatedproductoptionrows;
  this.selectedOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
};

Product.fromData = data => new Product(data);

function Option(data, products) {
  this.title = data.producttitle;
  this.id = data.id;
  
  this.products = products
    // Only include products that allow this option
    .filter(
      p => p.options.some(o => o.id === this.id)
    )
    // Create a computed checked property for each product-
    // option relation
    .map(p => {
      // The `option` objects in our product are different
      // from this instance. So we find our representation
      // via our id first.
      const linkedObj = p.options.find(o => o.id === this.id);
      
      return {
        checked: ko.computed({
          // Checked when this option is in the selectedOptions
          read: () => p.selectedOptions().includes(linkedObj),
          // When set to true, add our representation to the selection,
          // when set to false, remove it.
          write: val => val 
            ? p.selectedOptions.push(linkedObj)
            : p.selectedOptions.remove(linkedObj)
        }),
        title: p.title
      };
    });
}

var App = function(products, options) {
  this.products = products.map(Product.fromData);
  this.options = options.map(o => new Option(o, this.products));
};

ko.applyBindings(new App(products, options));


// Test data
function getProducts() {
  return [{
    id: "1",
    producttitle: "25-100",
    relatedproductoptionrows: [{
      id: "4",
      producttitle: '1 Year'
    }, {
      id: "5",
      producttitle: '2 Year'
    }, {
      id: "6",
      producttitle: '3 Year'
    }]
  }, {
    id: "2",
    producttitle: "101-250",
    relatedproductoptionrows: [{
      id: "7",
      producttitle: '1 Year'
    }, {
      id: "8",
      producttitle: '2 Year'
    }, {
      id: "9",
      producttitle: '3 Year'
    }]
  }, {
    id: "3",
    producttitle: "251-500",
    relatedproductoptionrows: [{
      id: "10",
      producttitle: '1 Year'
    }, {
      id: "11",
      producttitle: '2 Year'
    }, {
      id: "12",
      producttitle: '3 Year'
    }]
  }];
};

function getOptions() {
  return [{
        id: "4",
        producttitle: "1 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "5",
        producttitle: "2 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "6",
        producttitle: "3 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "7",
        producttitle: "1 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "8",
        producttitle: "2 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "9",
        producttitle: "3 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "10",
        producttitle: "1 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "11",
        producttitle: "2 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }, {
        id: "12",
        producttitle: "3 Year",
        relatedproductoptionrows: []
    }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li>
      <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
      <div data-bind="foreach: options">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedOptions, checkedValue: $data">
          <span data-bind="text: producttitle"></span>
        </label>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul data-bind="foreach: options">
    <li>
      <p data-bind="text: title"></p>
      <div data-bind="foreach: products">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked">
          <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```